# how to identify for the xml end tag while parsing using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I want to identify end tag of each element in the xml file.

Example :

```
<Bank>
    <Account>
        <Id1>1001</Id1>
        <Name1>Sony Corporation</Name1>
        <Amt1>1000000</Amt1>
        <age>23</age>
   </Account>
   <Account>
        <Id2>1002</Id2>
        <Name2>Sony Corporation</Name2>
        <Amt2>1000000</Amt2>
   </Account>
</Bank>
```

Now I want to identify the

```
</Account>
```

tag is closing.

How to identify such a end tag while parsing xml file using DOM?

Comment: I don't think this question makes sense. DOM does not give you individual start and end tags. It represents whole elements, which represent the start tag, end tag, and all the content in-between. The contents of the element are represented as the children of the DOM node that represents the element.

Comment: why do you want to detect the end tag?

Comment: I want to convert this xml document into my specific JSON format so I want to identify starting element,ending element, element child's and ending element tag.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is at a higher level of abstraction than this. It doesn't expose start and end tags, it exposes nodes, presented as a tree structure. If you tell us what you are trying to achieve (the problem you are trying to solve, not the way you are trying to solve it) then we could suggest the right approach.

Comment: This is actual task. Link- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627189/parsing-a-xml-file-and-convert-into-a-json-file-using-dom-parser-in-java?noredirect=1#comment62737252_37627189]

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(Account);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(Id1, parser.getValue(e, Id1));
            map.put(Name1, parser.getValue(e, Name1));
            map.put(Amt1, parser.getValue(e, Amt1));
            map.put(age, parser.getValue(e, age));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }
```

Comment: sohail I don't want to add nodes values into HashMap but I want to identify Account when it arrives and aslo I dont want any Hardcode. :-D