# How can an end-of-element be determined in an XML DOM Node Tree

Tags: xml, vba, dom

I would have added to the following thread but that would be a violation of the forum rule "But avoid Asking for help".
[how to identify for the xml end tag while parsing using DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614271/how-to-identify-for-the-xml-end-tag-while-parsing-using-dom)

The question in the thread above is also mine.  An alternative is to know how to capture the "GroupName" and each  within that group bypassing all information within < History> < /History>.

I'm using Excel 2016 VBA.
The KeePass XML has no known schema.

A simple node tree consisting of the high-level elements of the KeePass XML file are listed below to provide some semblance of clarity.  Entry detail (children) and most nodes have been ignored for simplicity.

```css
<KeePassFile>
   <Root>
      <Group>
         <Group>
            <Name>GroupName</Name>
            <Entry>
               <History>
                  <Entry>
                  </Entry>
                  <Entry>
                  </Entry>
               </History>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
            </Entry>
         </Group>
      </Group>
      <DeletedObjects />
   </Root>
</KeePassFile>
```

The reason for my attempt is to load a KeePass XML file into Excel using Excel VBA and the XML DOM library.  There appears to be no schema and various "levels" use the same Nodes E.G.  I tried using XPath but got nowhere. getElementsByTagName seemed promising and even worked for two  elements but when done with the second entry the parent.nextsibliing went off into limbo.

Since no information between < History>< /History> is wanted I could determine both the next sibling and the parent's next sibling and use the first of the two nodes reached to "determine" the end.

I could also assume all elements that immediately follow a < /Entry> are known and use them.  I know of < Entry>, < History>, and < DeletedObjects> but, others may exist.

Comment: It would be best to include some of the code you've already tried, and describe exactly what the problem is with it.  Right now your question looks like a pretty standard XML parsing exercise with no tricky parts.

Answer (score 0):

DOM is a tree-level view of the data. An element node in this tree corresponds to a start-tag/end-tag pair, and the children of the node represent everything found between the start tag and end tag. There is therefore no separate representation of start tags and end tags in DOM (or other more modern tree models): the two tags are collapsed into a single node object. (Which might explain why so many people misuse the word "tag" to mean "element node").

If you want to ignore the history element, just ignore the element node, you don't need to worry about start and end tags.

Comment: I may have figured out a method.  Will post later, if it works or not.  Perhaps you will be able to point me in another direction or improve my mehtod.  Only snippets will be posted due to the 600 character limit.  To actually see an example of the XML I am working with export a KeePass (available from Sourceforge) file as XML.

Comment: Have code working on simple KeePass XML but it currently fails on a more complex version where <Group> has 4 "levels" and <Entry> has 6.  Unable to post code sample due to character limit.  Need to convert to using objects only as I'm still using childnodes.item(0) format for some of the code since I have not yet figured out how to use SingleSelectNode and it should help in handling those deeper <Entry> nodes.  Sorry for the bother.  THANKS for responding.

Comment: That sounds like a new question, so post a new question, and give enough information so that people have a reasonable chance of working out where you have gone wrong.